# Flutter : A box/cointainer as elements of a list view

Tags: flutter, listview, containers

The widget defined below is essentially a container with an icon and text.

```
class _RecordState extends State<Record> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.cyanAccent,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(24)),
      ),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget> [
          Icon(
            Icons.arrow_forward_ios_sharp,
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
          Text(
            "Hello"
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to pass this as an element in listview, because in the problem I need to solve, I would have to display these containers a particular number of times depending on the situation. But I simply could not find a way to do it.

```
List<Record> getListElements(){
    var items = List<Record>.generate(1000, (msg) => Record());
    return items;
  }
  Widget getListView(){
    var listItems = getListElements();
    var listview = ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context,index){
          return ListTile(
            //what do I do?
          );
        }
    );
    return listview;
}
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming you want a `Record` widget inside the `ListTile`. Keep in mind you have the option to use `leading` `title` `subtitle` or `trailing` as to where to insert the widget. This example uses `leading`.

```
Widget getListView() {
  var listItems = getListElements();
  var listview = ListView.builder(
      itemCount: listItems.length, // add the count
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListTile(
          leading: listItems[index], // using each index of the list
        );
      });
  return listview;
}
```